# How to fix "selected does not follow Java naming conventions" durning WS creation in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss, apache-axis

I'm trying to create a webservice in Eclipse.

Here is my class(testWS.java):

```
package ws.impl;

public class testWS {

    public float celsiusToFarenheit ( float celsius )
        { return (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32; }
    public float farenheitToCelsius ( float farenheit )
        { return (farenheit - 32) * 5 / 9; }
}
```

I go to:
right click / Web Services / Create Web Service

Then I get the following error message:
"The service implementation selected does not follow Java naming conventions."

![JBoss error][1]

I'm on JBoss 7.1.1, Java 7 Update 45, Axis2 v1.6.2.

Comment: The class name should start with a capital letter. `TestWS`.

Comment: You are correct.  Actually, this is a stub to test.  Which bring me to the next error.


IWAB0379E Unable to open 

http://localhost:8080/Test_WS/services/TestWS?wsdl.


IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.


WSDLException


WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: 

http://localhost:8080/Test_WS/services/TestWS?wsdl

Comment: did you have a look in your wsdl file? Maybe you have to rebuild/update the file with the new class name. If this is the case change your server setting to deploy at server start.

Answer (score 0):

Use CXF and don't forget to remove services/* mapping for Axis from web.xml